# NEWBIE, is this turning into spaghetti code?

Tags: vba, excel

So I am literally 24hrs into trying to learn this. I know that this can be simplified into smaller methods and functions, but I not quite that far yet. So this code, the way it stands works and I haven't made it crash too hard yet. Any help and suggestions are awesomely grateful.
Thanks guys.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim myInOut As String

Dim myToolType As String

Dim myOrderNumber As String

Dim myQTY As Integer

Dim myToolDesc As String

Dim myEmployee As String

Dim myDate As Date

Dim myLastRowA As Long

Dim myLastRowB As Long

Dim myRow As Long

Dim myNewTool As Long

Dim myNewRow As Long

myDate = DateTime.Now

myLastRowA = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").End(xlDown).Row - 2

If ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 2).Value = "" Then

    Exit Sub
End If


'Finds the Matching Row for the In/Out Order Number AND Updates QTY

'MsgBox "LastRowA - " & myLastRowA       'Debugging

For a = 1 To myLastRowA

    myNewTool = True
    myLastRowB = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A3").End(xlDown).Row
    'MsgBox "LastRowB - " & myLastRowB & vbCrLf & "OrderNumber - " & myOrderNumber   'Debugging
        With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
            myInOut = .Cells(3, 1).Value
            myToolType = .Cells(3, 2).Value
            myOrderNumber = .Cells(3, 3).Value
            myQTY = .Cells(3, 4).Value
            myToolDesc = .Cells(3, 5).Value
            myEmployee = .Cells(3, 6).Value

            For b = 1 To myLastRowB
                If ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(b, 2).Value = myOrderNumber Then
                    myRow = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(b, 2).Row
                    'MsgBox "True " & myRow      'Debugging
                        If myInOut = "IN" Then
                            'Adds In/Out QTY to the Stock QTY
                            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(myRow, 4).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(myRow, 4).Value + myQTY
                            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(3).Delete
                            myNewTool = False
                        ElseIf myInOut = "OUT" Then
                            'Subtracts In/Out QTY to the Stock QTY
                            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(myRow, 4).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(myRow, 4).Value - myQTY
                            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(3).Delete
                            myNewTool = False
                        End If
                End If
            Next b
        If myNewTool = True Then
            myNewRow = myLastRowB + 1
            'MsgBox "NewTool" & myNewTool        'Debugging
            If myInOut = "IN" Then
                ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(myNewRow, 1).Value = myToolType
                ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(myNewRow, 2).Value = myOrderNumber
                ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(myNewRow, 3).Value = myToolDesc
                ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(myNewRow, 4).Value = myQTY
                ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(3).Delete
            ElseIf myInOut = "OUT" Then
                MsgBox "THE ORDER NUMBER OF " & myOrderNumber & " IS NOT IN THE DATABASE" & vbCrLf & myToolType & " " & myToolDesc & vbCrLf & "DOES NOT EXIST. PLEASE EDIT YOUR SELECTION."
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    End With
Next a

End Sub
```

Comment: Use variables for your worksheets eg `Dim sht2 As WorkSheet: Set sht2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")` will reduce the volume of code and make it more easily modifiable/maintainable.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: If you want to find the last row it's better to use (eg) `sht2.Cells(rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)` rather than using `End(xlDown)` which will be sensitive to (1) only having one row (2) having gaps in your data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a lot of functionality in one `Sub`, so yes, it's trending towards spaghetti code.

People have different opinions over how long a `Sub` should be, but as a rule of thumb, you generally want routines, functions, and other units of code to be no more than 10-20 lines; exceptions should be pretty rare. You have about 60 lines, even after removing comments and blank lines. That's getting up there. You also have a dozen variables, nested loops, and lots of `if` statements. The [cyclomatic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) of your code is thus getting rather high.

Also, as pointed out in the comments, you reuse several identifiers like `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3")` multiple times. This makes the code hard to read and subject to breaking if anything changes and affects one of those values while your code is running.

So, yes, you should try to break this down into smaller pieces.